# Calculating gradient of scalar with vector jacobian products

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, jacobian

I am trying to calculate the $\phi$ gradient of the scalar
\begin{align*} 
F = \sum_{i=0}^nf^T\dfrac{\partial h_i}{\partial \theta}^T\lambda_i \tag{1}
\end{align*}
$f, \theta \in \mathcal{R}^{m}$, $h_i \in \mathcal{R}^k$, $h_i$ is a shorthand for $h_i(x_i, \theta)$ where $x_i \in \mathcal{R}^k$. $\lambda_i \in \mathcal{R}^k$ and are defined by
\begin{align*} 
&\lambda_{n} = 0 \\
&\lambda_{i-1} = \dfrac{\partial h_i}{\partial x_i}^T\lambda_i + \dfrac{\partial p_i}{\partial x_i}^T\beta_i(\phi)
\end{align*}
where $\beta_i$ and $p_i = p_i(x_i)$ are scalars.

Supposedly, using vector-jacobian products (i.e. reverse mode differentiation) the gradient $\nabla_{\phi}F$ can be calculated in some constant times complexity as $F$. However, after much trying I am unable to express the gradient using only vector-jacobian products. I can only get it down to either matrix-jacobian products, or jacobian-vector products. Either way, this means calculating the gradient would scale with the dimension of $x$, meaning it would not be constant, but scale with $k$. This leaves me confused as to whether I am doing something wrong, or there is some sort of caveat to reverse differentiation that I'm not aware of. I highly suspect the former but I'm not really sure what to do differently.

### Gradient calculation

##### Method A

Using
\begin{align*} 
\dfrac{\partial \lambda_{i-1}}{\partial \phi} = \dfrac{\partial h_i}{\partial x_i}^T\dfrac{\partial \lambda_i}{\partial \phi} + \dfrac{\partial p_i}{\partial x_i}^T\dfrac{\partial \beta_i}{\partial \phi}
\end{align*}
so that the gradient is
\begin{align*} 
\sum_{i=0}^nf^T\dfrac{\partial h_i}{\partial \theta}^T\dfrac{\partial \lambda_i }{\partial \phi} .
\end{align*}
You can massage this further, but you always end up having to form some sort of matrix in $\mathcal{R}^{k\times k}$.

##### Method B

The gradient is
\begin{align*} 
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\xi_i^T\dfrac{\partial p_{i+1}}{\partial x_{i+1}}^T\dfrac{\partial \beta_{1+i}}{\partial \phi}
\end{align*}
where $\xi$ are given by
\begin{align*} 
&\xi_0^T = f^T\dfrac{\partial h_0}{\partial \theta}^T \\
& \xi_{i+1}^T = f^T\dfrac{\partial h_{i+1}}{\theta}^T + \xi_i^T\dfrac{\partial h_{i+1}}{\partial x_{i+1}}^T
\end{align*}
In this case you have to calculate $\partial h_{i+1}/\partial x_{i+1}$.

Comment: I've asked a simplified version of this question on ai.se https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/28240/gradient-of-scalar-objective-cannot-be-efficiently-calculated. Also I now doubt that it's possible to do better than the 2 methods presented in this question - i.e. I no longer think it's possible to calculate this gradient efficiently. I'm still looking for an answer about what exactly is the property of the scalar function F which causes this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: **We can calculate $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial \phi}$ efficiently, either by using jacobian vector products, or nested vector jacobian products, which are equivalent to jacobian vector products. Also, jacobian vector products aren't necessarily bad when talking about gradients of compositions of functions.**

To explain this, first I'm going to cite two definitions/results from [1].

### VJP vs JVP

For some function $f(x) : \mathcal{R}^m \rightarrow \mathcal{R}^n$, the **vector jacobian product** is defined as
\begin{align*} 
\text{vjp}(u, f, x) := u^T\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}
\end{align*}
for some constant vector $u$. The time complexity of this vjp is
\begin{align*} 
TIME[f, \text{vjp}(u, f, x)] <= 4 \,TIME[f]
\end{align*}
That is to say, the time complexity of the vjp is bounded by a constant factor of 4 times the complexity of $f$.

For the same function $f(x)$, the **jacobian vector product** is defined as
\begin{align*} 
\text{jvp}(f, x, v) := \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}v
\end{align*}
The time complexity of this jvp is
\begin{align*} 
TIME[f, \text{jvp}(f, x, v)] <= \frac{5}{2} \,TIME[f]
\end{align*}
At this point, if you were me when I asked this question, you're asking yourself, "wait, they both have a constant computation complexity?" You might think that jacobian vector products, also known as forward mode differentiation, are to be avoided, whereas we only want to use vector jacobian products.

### Scalar objectives and when JVP go bad

To understand why JVP get a bad rap, let's consider the function $h(\theta) : \mathcal{R}^m \rightarrow \mathcal{R}$. In a common use case, we want to compute the gradient $\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial \theta}$. If we want to compute this gradient with a vjp, its simply
\begin{align*} 
\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial \theta} = \text{vjp}(1, h, \theta)
\end{align*}
where $1$ is a scalar. Since we can compute this gradient with a single vjp, it follows that we can compute the gradient with the equivalent of (at most) 4 evaluations of $h$. Now lets say we try use jvp instead.
\begin{align*} 
\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial \theta} = \dfrac{\partial h}{\partial \theta}I = \begin{bmatrix} \text{jvp}(h, \theta, e_1) & \text{jvp}(h, \theta, e_2) & \ldots & \text{jvp}(h, \theta, e_m) \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
where $I$ is the $\mathcal{R}^m$ identity matrix, and $e_i$ is a vector with 1 at index $i$ and 0s everywhere else. Now it's clear to evaluate the gradient we don't need a single jvp, but actually we need $m$ jvp. So in this context jvp go very wrong.

### Relevance to the original question

As stated in the question, we have
\begin{align*} 
\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial \phi} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\xi_i^T\dfrac{\partial p_{i+1}}{\partial x_{i+1}}^T\dfrac{\partial \beta_{1+i}}{\partial \phi}
\end{align*}
where $\xi$ are given by
\begin{align*} 
&\xi_0^T = f^T\dfrac{\partial h_0}{\partial \theta}^T \\
& \xi_{i+1}^T = f^T\dfrac{\partial h_{i+1}}{\theta}^T + \xi_i^T\dfrac{\partial h_{i+1}}{\partial x_{i+1}}^T
\end{align*}
Now the $\xi$ can be efficiently calculated using jvp.
\begin{align*}
& \xi_{i} = \text{jvp}(h_i, \theta, f) + \text{jvp}(h_i, x_i, \xi_{i-1})
\end{align*}
Then gradient is simply
\begin{align*} 
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \langle\text{vjp}(1, p_{i+1}, x_{i}), \xi_i\rangle\text{vjp}(1, \beta_{i+1}, \phi) 
\end{align*}
So in this case, it's simple to calculate $\xi$ with jvp, but not with vjp.

As a final point, I'll mention that Hyperplane's answer could also work - this is because two nested vjp is equivalent to jvp.
\begin{align*} 
\text{vjp}(c, \text{vjp}(y, g, \phi), y) = \text{jvp}(g, \phi, c)^T
\end{align*}
So as an alternative to using jvp, you can use nested vjp instead.

### **Reference**

[1] "Evaluating Derivatives: principles and techniques of algorithmic differentiation" by Griewank, Walther (2008). Chapter 3.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about $F$, it is a fact that computing the gradient of any scalar function in reverse mode is comparable to evaluating the function. You are probably just getting irritated by the reverse indexing, additional derivatives present and non-standard notation.

To simplify notation, let $A_i = \big(\frac{\partial h_i}{\partial\theta}\big)^T$, $B_i = \big(\frac{\partial h_{i}}{\partial x_{i}}\big)^T$, $v_i =\big(\frac{\partial p_{i}}{\partial x_{i}}\big)^T$. So we want

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \sum_{i=n}^0 F_i, \qquad F_i = f^TA_i \lambda_i , \qquad \lambda_{i-1} = B_i \lambda_i + v_i \beta_i
$$

Then

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} F_i &= \frac{\partial f^TA_i \lambda_i}{\partial \phi} 
\\&= \frac{\partial f^TA_i \lambda_i}{\partial \lambda_i}\frac{\partial \lambda_i}{\partial \phi}
\\&= \frac{\partial f^TA_i \lambda_i}{\partial \lambda_i}\frac{\partial B_i \lambda_{i+1} + v_{i+1} \beta_{i+1}}{\partial \phi}
\\&= \frac{\partial f^TA_i \lambda_i}{\partial \lambda_i}\Big(\frac{\partial  B_i\lambda_{i+1}}{\partial \lambda_{i+1}}\frac{\partial\lambda_{i+1}}{\partial \phi}+ \frac{\partial v_{i+1}\beta_{i+1}}{\partial \beta_{i+1}}\frac{\partial \beta_{i+1}}{\partial \phi}\Big)
\\&= \frac{\partial f^TA_i \lambda_i}{\partial \lambda_i}\Big(\frac{\partial  B_i\lambda_{i+1}}{\partial \lambda_{i+1}}\Big(\frac{\partial  B_{i+1}\lambda_{i+2}}{\partial \lambda_{i+2}}\frac{\partial\lambda_{i+2}}{\partial \phi}+ \frac{\partial v_{i+2}\beta_{i+2}}{\partial \beta_{i+2}}\frac{\partial \beta_{i+2}}{\partial \phi}\Big)+ \frac{\partial v_{i+1}\beta_{i+1}}{\partial \beta_{i+1}}\frac{\partial \beta_{i+1}}{\partial \phi}\Big)
\\&=\ldots
\end{aligned}$$

And then we just accumulate gradients from the left: $z^T_0 = \frac{\partial f^TA_i \lambda_i}{\partial \lambda_i}$ is a row vector. Then $z_1^T = z_0^T\frac{\partial  B_i\lambda_{i+1}}{\partial \lambda_{i+1}}$ is a VJP, $z_2^T = z_1^T\frac{\partial  B_{i+1}\lambda_{i+2}}{\partial \lambda_{i+2}}$ is a VJP, etc. pp.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think this is correct. Note that the key difficulty is that $f^TA_i$ cannot be calculated as a vector jacobian product, since it is actually a jacobian vector product. 
Moreover, $z_0^TB_i$ etc. are not vector jacobian products, again these are jacobian vector products

Answer (score 0):

Reading you post on https://ai.stackexchange.com made the problem much clearer. Given

$$ \begin{align*} 
F =  c^T \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial \phi}^T y
\end{align*} = \langle c,\,\text{vjp}(y, g, \phi)\rangle
$$

where $y=h(x, \theta)$ you do not see how to express $\frac{\partial }{\partial \phi} F$ as VJPs. But again, it's really straightforward:

$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta} F
= 
\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}
\langle c,\,\text{vjp}(y, g, \phi)\rangle
= c^T \frac{\partial \text{vjp}(y, g, \phi)}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}
$$

where

- $z_0 ^T = c^T \frac{\partial \text{vjp}(y, g, \phi)}{\partial y} = \text{vjp}(c, \text{vjp}(y,g,\phi), y)$ is the VJP of $c$ with the jacobian of the function $y\mapsto \text{vjp}(y, g, \phi)$
- $z_1^T = z_0^T \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} = \text{vjp}(z_0, y, \theta)$ is the VJP of $z_0$ with the jacobian of the function $y\colon \theta \mapsto h(x, \theta)$.

You can treat $y\mapsto \text{vjp}(y, g, \phi)$ as any other vector-to-vector function in this context.

Comment: I still disagree as your reasoning is still the same as your previous answer - and again, I conclude what you call VJP are actually JVP. However I have done some more research and actually found that JVP can also be calculated efficiently. This fact seems to not really be stated anywhere and I am writing my own answer to this question.

Comment: @Taw I literally wrote you down the VJPs explicitly, so I do not understand how you can claim they are not VJPs. If I am wrong I would really like to know it so please expand on your reasoning on where the mistake is in $\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta} F = \text{vjp}(\text{vjp}(c, \text{vjp}(y,g,\phi), y), y, \theta)$

Comment: @Taw And btw. that JVPs can be computed efficiently is common knowledge, since a jacobian vector product is equal to a directional derivate $J_f(a) \cdot v = \frac{d}{d\epsilon} f(a+\epsilon v)|_{\epsilon=0}$, one only needs to perform a single forward pass using [dual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number). However, then you are using forward mode differentiation, which is inefficient when computing the gradient of a scalar function.